# Ignoring an optional suffix with a greedy regex

Tags: .net, regex, greedy, regex-greedy

I'm performing regex matching in .NET against strings that look like this:

```
1;#Lists/General Discussion/Waffles Win
2;#Lists/General Discussion/Waffles Win/2_.000
3;#Lists/General Discussion/Waffles Win/3_.000
```

I need to match the URL portion without the numbers at the end, so that I get this:

```
Lists/General Discussion/Waffles Win
```

This is the regex I'm trying:

```
(?:\d+;#)(?<url>.+)(?:/\d+_.\d+)*
```

The problem is that the last group is being included as part of the middle group's match. I've also tried without the * at the end but then only the first string above matches and not the rest.

I have the multi-line option enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `'(?.+)'` supposed to be? It is invalid regex.

Comment: @MizardX: Markdown screwed the regex. I'll reformat to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few different alternatives:

```
@"^\d+;#([^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*?)(?:/\d+_\.\d+)?$"
```

This matches as few path segments as possible, followed by an optional last part, and the end of the line.

```
@"^\d+;#([^/]+(?:/(?!\d+_\.\d+$)[^/]+)*)"
```

This matches as many path segments as possible, as long as it is not the digit-part at the end of the line.

```
@"^\d+;#(.*?)(?:/\d+_\.\d+)?$"
```

This matches as few characters as possible, followed by an optional last part, and the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you, last one works. Never thought of matching the end line itself - I think that's the major difference.

Comment: The difference is that it uses a lazy quantifier (`.*?`) instead of a greedy one (`.+`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
^(\d+;#)([^/]+(/[^\d][^/]*)*)
```

and get the 2nd group. The first group matches the `1;#`; the second group is split into the first part or the URL (assumed to contain any character other than /), then match any number of groups of /, followed by a non-digit, followed by anything other than /.

Tested on [this site](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx), appears to do what you want. Give it a try with some more samples.