# Regex to match address and optional suffix

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have addresses in two formats:

```
SomeHouse,
Holbrook,
Belper,
Derbyshire,
DE56 0RR
```

and

```
SomeHouse,
Holbrook,
Belper,
Derbyshire,
DE56 0RR(123123123123)
```

The number only ever appears right at the end, is always in brackets and always 12 digits.

I am trying to get a regex to match two groups ... the address and the number (if it is there).

It is a head banger (for my inregexperienced self) since i cant get my expression to work on both types of address.

I have

```
(?<address>.*)(?<bracketsandnum>\((?<num>[0-9]{12})\))$
```

which also uses a group to match the brackets - not so sure i need that bit :) certainly not as a named group anyway.

Please advise!

Cheers,
James.

---

### Update

I have used the answer provided by Martinho, Qtax. Many thanks to them.
Now i understand a bit more, i see my question is similar to the following:

[Ignoring an optional suffix with a greedy regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422434/ignoring-an-optional-suffix-with-a-greedy-regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the second group optional with `?`, and use a non-greedy match in the first group (by modifying `*` with `?`). Something like this:

```
^(?<address>.*?)(?:\((?<num>\d{12})\))?$
```

Comment: @Martinho, Qtax, may i officially upgrade 'something like' to 'exactly like'! It works ... thankyou very much.

Comment: Please could you explain what the ?: bit means?

Comment: @user: it makes a non-capturing group. It means that there won't be a `Group` in the `Match` for the portion it captures. I think @Qtax assumed you didn't care about capturing the parenthesis, only the numbers. If you do want them, go ahead an make a named group like you did in your original regex.

Comment: @Martinho, thank you again. I actually understand the little fecker now. Qtax was right, those brackets are unwanted.